# android webview INVALID_STATE_ERR

Tags: android, jquery, android-webview, autosuggest

I have web application that have autoSuggest.js lib and it works fine in all browsers fine but when I used android webview and when I put character it make the request fine and get the result but when I click on one item to selected it I got this error in logcat and nothing happen.

```
 INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11: An attempt was made to use an
 object that is not, or is no longer, usable. at
 http://192.168.1.236:8080/resources/js/lib/jquery.min.js
```

any help please...

Jquery v1.7.2

Comment: Any insights about this issue?